# Short-lived TV series about group that enters other people's dreams

Tags: story-identification, tv, dreams

This was the mid 90's. It revolved around a group of scientists who had the technology to enter a sleeping person's mind. When interacting in the sleeper's dreams they solved mysteries or helped the sleeper resolve issues the dreams were about - the first episode was about a Gulf War veteran and (I think, it's been a while) his short-lived twin brother, at the end of the episode he signed on with the scientists.

I do recall the leader of the group  had a wife in a coma, he intended to find a way to bring her out of it but the series folded before that could happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [Sleepwalkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleepwalkers_(TV_series)) (1997)

[image]

Description from IMDB:

> Short-lived series about a group of dream researchers who use special sleep-beds to electronically send operatives into people's dreams, where they can witness first-hand their subjects' visions and nightmares, and interact with them in an effort to sort them out. They're available for hire by individuals, as well as wider-ranging problems, such as a medical outbreak in a small town.

Here's the synopsis of the first episode, from Wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> In the opener, neurophysiologist Nathan Bradford tries to help a **former Air Force pilot** interpret a recurring nightmare in which a shadowy figure pursues him over a forbidding landscape.

I was only able to find this clip on YouTube, with Naomi Watts:

Comment: I never realised _Inception_ had a prequel TV show.

Comment: I swear to Dog I have no memory of writing this answer

Comment: the Sleepwalkers have been in your brain! You knew too much!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite see also trailer for Dreamscape (1984)  https://youtu.be/4ybHzYtF3ZM